# How to Plot realistic curves using Scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

My python program is able to plot graphs but it's curves are unrealistic.

for example : [image]

How can I smooth-en the graph using Scipy? I have seen previous tutorials regarding this matter but they tended to use numpy and its arange() features. Since my program doesn't derive the points to be plotted from numpy I think it's features are useless in this scenario.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sympy.symbols('x')

class Interface(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.x_from_1 = ttk.Label(self.parent, text= ' X values should be from : ')
        self.x_from_2 = ttk.Label(self.parent, text = ' To : ')
        self.x_from_1_inp = ttk.Entry(self.parent)
        self.x_from_2_inp = ttk.Entry(self.parent)

        self.equation_label = ttk.Label(self.parent,text = 'Equation : ')
        self.equation = ttk.Entry(self.parent)

        self.submit = ttk.Button(self.parent,text='Plot',command= self.Plot)

# Grid Allocations Here
        self.x_from_1.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.x_from_2.grid(column=5,row=0)
        self.x_from_1_inp.grid(column=1,row=0)
        self.x_from_2_inp.grid(column=10,row=0)

        self.equation_label.grid(column = 0,row=3)
        self.equation.grid(column=1,row=3,ipadx= 35)

        self.submit.grid(column=10,row=5)
# Grid Allocations End Here


    def Plot(self):
        x_vals = range(int(self.x_from_1_inp.get()),int(self.x_from_2_inp.get()))
        eq = eval(self.equation.get())
        self.prepare_table(x_vals,eq)
        plt.plot(x_vals,self.y_values)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

    def prepare_table(self,x_values,equation):
        y = []
        for i in x_values:
            y.append(equation.subs(x,i))
        self.y_values = y
        return self.y_values

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title('Graphs')
app = Interface(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could fit a quadratic to this data with `numpy.polyfit`, then plot that. Alternatively, look at the LO(W)ESS implementation in BioPython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d): [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)

```
...
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy

class Interface(ttk.Frame):
    ....
    def Plot(self):
        x_vals = range(int(self.x_from_1_inp.get()),int(self.x_from_2_inp.get()))
        eq = eval(self.equation.get())
        self.prepare_table(x_vals,eq)
        f = interp1d(x_vals, self.y_values, kind='cubic')
        x_new = numpy.linspace(x_vals[0], x_vals[-1], (x_vals[-1]-x_vals[0])*4)
        plt.plot(x_new, f(x_new))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: what does the accuracy of the curved line drawn depend on? and what does this line do `x_new = numpy.linspace(x_vals[0], x_vals[-1], (x_vals[-1]-x_vals[0])*4)`

Comment: @KDawG, Sorry, I don't know about the accuracy of the curved line. It may depend on size of `x_new` and `kind` (one of `linear`, `nearest`, `zero`, `slinear`, `quadratic`, `cubic`).

Comment: @KDawG `numpy.linspace(x, y, n)` yields `n` numbers between `x` and `y` (`x`,`y` inclusive). For example `numpy.linspace(0, 2, 10)` yields `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]`.

Comment: @KDawG,  `x_new = numpy.linspace(x_vals[0], x_vals[-1], (x_vals[-1]-x_vals[0])*4)` was used to generate more numbers inbetween X values.

Comment: Thanks man, great explanation and I modified your code a bit to `x_new = numpy.linspace(x_vals[0], x_vals[-1], len(x_vals)**2*4)` now damn accurate